# Extjs with google Ajax Language Api

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, extjs

Can we use google AJAX Language API with EXTjs?
I have tried example for translation, I have one html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="F:\vaishali.g\ext-3.1.0\resources\css\ext-all.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="F:\vaishali.g\ext-3.1.0\adapter\ext\ext-base.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="F:\vaishali.g\ext-3.1.0\ext-all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="F:\vaishali.g\ext-3.1.0\ext-all-debug.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="F:\vaishali.g\Assignments\EXTJS\typemarathi.js"></script>

 </HEAD>

 <body>
    Type in Hindi (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)<br>
   <input type="text" id="myid" name="myname">
  </body>
</HTML>
```

and typemarathi.js

google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });

```
  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage:
            google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage:
            [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.MARATHI],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
    // options.
    var control =
        new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

    // Enable transliteration in the editable DIV with id
    // 'transliterateDiv'.
    control.makeTransliteratable([myname]);
  }
 google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

it works fine. But if I write the textfield in extjs

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
var form1=new Ext.FormPanel({
            renderTo:document.body,
            frame:true,
            title:'My First Form',
            widyh:250,
            items:[{
                xtype:'textfield',
                fieldLabel:'First name',
                name:'firstname'

                    }
                ]
});
});
```

and try to pass firstname (name attribute to **control.makeTransliteratable([firstname])**)
then it does not work... it says "invalid id error". But if I pass->(html textfiled name to it) **control.makeTransliteratable([myname])** it works fine.

Comment: yes, you can. why would you think not? this question requires more elaboration.

Comment: Multiple ?'s or !'s in succession = auto downvote

Answer (score 3):

**Yes   we   can!**

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would not be able to -- actually, I'm pretty sure you can, like you can use it with other frameworks, like jQuery or Prototype.

*(Did you run into any kind of specific trouble ? If so, you might want to edit your question, to provide us with more details)*

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me based on your code, but if you are passing the **string value** 'firstname' (with quotes) to the Google lib, then it should work fine I would assume.  However, if you are passing an object reference (which it looks like in your example) then you would have to pass the underlying field reference, not the Ext TextField object reference (like `myTextField.getEl()`).