# Extjs AJAX Language Api

Tags: ajax, api, extjs

can we use google AJAX Language API with EXTjs????? 
i have tried example for translitration i have one html file 
and typemarathi.js

```
google.load("elements", "1", { packages: "transliteration" });

function onLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.MARATHI],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
    // options.
    var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

    // Enable transliteration in the editable DIV with id
    // 'transliterateDiv'.
    control.makeTransliteratable([myname]);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

it works fine.

but if i write the textfield in extjs

```
Ext.onReady(function(){ 
    var form1=new Ext.FormPanel({ 
            renderTo:document.body, 
            frame:true, 
            title:'My First Form', 
            widyh:250, 
            items:[{ xtype:'textfield', fieldLabel:'First name', name:'firstname'}]
        });

});
```

and try to pass firstname (name attribute to control.makeTransliteratable([firstname])) then it does not work... it says invalid id error

but if i pass->(html textfiled name to it) control.makeTransliteratable([myname]) it works fine

(i want to type and display multiple nonEnglish languages data 
programatically  frontend i used EXTjs is there any another way to do so if yes the suggest me. pls..

Comment: Is this the same question that you asked an hour earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333826/extjs-with-google-ajax-language-api

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Besides someone should clean his code, thats hurrible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But you should know that ExtJs automatically generates identifiers for html elements:

```
html:
<div class="x-form-item  x-form-label-left x-box-item" id="ext-gen27" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <label style="width: 55px;" class="x-form-item-label" id="ext-gen28">Send To:</label>
    <div style="padding-left: 60px; width: 668px;" class="x-form-element" id="ext-gen26">
        <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus" id="ext-gen24" style="width: 668px;">
            <input type="text" name="to" id="ext-comp-1002" autocomplete="off" size="24" class=" x-form-text x-form-field x-form-focus" style="width: 651px;">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

js:
....
items: [{
        xtype: 'combo',
        store: ['test@example.com', 'someone-else@example.com' ],
        plugins: [ Ext.ux.FieldReplicator, Ext.ux.FieldLabeler ],
        fieldLabel: 'Send To',
        name: 'to'
    }]
```

As I understand you need to translate the label. In order to do this you should get the id of the label. To do this you can use [TextField's label](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.TextField) property (myField.label.id). If you want to translate a lot of elements then probably it'll be better for you to use something like this:

```
var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
var labelIds = [];

Ext.each(Ext.select('label'), function(item){
    labelIds.push(item.id);
});

control.makeTransliteratable(labelIds);
```

But be aware that you should call this only after rendering all elements. Also you can write a [some plugin](http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/extension-or-plugin/) that will inject this functionality into 'render' method. Writing a plugin is a better but a bit more harder way.